# How can I compile OpenCV with QT support on python?

Tags: python, qt, opencv

While creating a button it terminal said "The library is compiled without QT support in function 'cv::createButton'"

I am using PyCharm Professional

Comment: opencv is not a gui library. use qt (or tkinter), if you want guis (with buttons). -- where did you get your opencv from? are you really asking how to compile OpenCV? that's documented in plenty of places, in plenty of ways. please review [ask]. you do the research. if you have a specific problem that nobody has solved before, then you have a proper question.

Comment: Hello @ChristophRackwitz, sorry for the way that I presented my question. OpenCV is not a GUI library but it has functions to create buttons on window. I did some research apparently I have to use cmake to build openCV with qt support and install it.